# default timezone error in php

Tags: php, datetime, kohana, silverstripe

I got the following error/warning while tring to install Kohana/SilverStripe.
What does it mean and What do I do for it?

```
Warning:
date_default_timezone_get():
It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for '5.5/no DST' instead in C:\Server\apache\htdocs\kohana\system\core\Kohana.php on line 136
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I hate those kinds of cryptic error messages where it leaves you with no idea of how it was triggered, why it's an error in the first place, and how to fix it... wait

Comment: I really don't see this as a cryptic message, it says very clearly that the timezone was not set properly and you should use data_default_timezone to do so.

Comment: problem is that I looked up in the php.ini and saw that default time zone could be set. I thought giving explicit definition there would resolve matters that it would not generate the warning. But it turned out elsewise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an error, but a warning, so it does not block your app from working.

Explicitly set the right timezone using date_default_timezone_set() in C:\Server\apache\htdocs\kohana\system\core\Kohana.php on line 136

You have to choose among [valid timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)

---

### Edit

As the warning message itself states you actually have a more clean choice then editing a third party software file. I.e. configuring PHP as it should be.

- edit your `php.ini` and adjust the value of `date.timezone = America/New_York`

or

- use a `php_value` directive in your web server config to set it in your *vhost configuration* or `.htaccess`: `php_value date.timezone America/New_York`

Comment: oh! I was trying to do that in php.ini during my self medication procedure! Thanks!

Comment: Suggesting to modify a framework or libraries core-files? That's not a good suggestion as it is the wrong place and will break updates. Instead fix the servers or applications PHP configuration as outlined in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11181131/367456), which is the concrete place to modify such.

Comment: @hakre I agree, it is a fix-the-issue answer .. In fact the answer is already given by the error message, I simply reported the simpler to implement for a  not-so-skiled user (otherwise he already had fixed it using the warn message suggestion) .. I'll edit my answer to be more complete. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The OP's comment to his own question above implies that the default timezone cannot be set in php.ini, which is not true — in fact, in many cases setting it there is *preferred*. And since this SO answer is one of the first hits in Google for "php default timezone error", I'll save others some lost sanity.

A very common cause of this error is not so much to misspell the zone city or country (e.g. "New York", "Los Angeles") in the php.ini file being used, but instead, to include embedded spaces rather than underscores in the identifier, and thus "misspell" the full constant.

This will also do what you want, without having to set it on every page at runtime (verified on PHP 5.4 and 5.3, in Windows, Linux and OSX):

In *php.ini*:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York
;               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  * Must_Use_Underscores *
```

Also, if you've checked and re-checked the spelling and are *certain* it's right, make sure you're editing the *actual* php.ini file that's being used:

Web context (create a test file *test.php*, and then confirm the `date.timezone` there):

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Command line Linux/OSX:

```
$ php -i | grep "timezone"
```

Command line Windows:

```
C:\> php -i | find "timezone"
```

The precedence order for retrieving the default date timezone configuration is spelled out in detail [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the ability to change `php.ini`, add this to your `_ss_environment.php` or `mysite/_config.php` files:

`date_default_timezone_set('...');`

where `...` is one of the valid PHP timezones.